# Как привязать слушателя к конкретной таблице

Tags: javascript, html5, javascript-events

**Доброго времени!**

Подскажите пожалуйста как привязать слушателя к конкретной таблице?

Почему не получается привязать слушателя к конкретной таблице вот таким образом (так не работает):

```html
document.querySelector('table.name_class_table').addEventListener("click", ({target}) => {
        });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
       document.querySelector('table.name_class_table').addEventListener("click", ({target}) => {
        var tr = target.closest("tbody > tr");
        if(!tr) return;
        var position = tr.querySelector("td.geo").textContent;//Берём нужную ячейку
        position = position.split(/\s+/).map(Number); //Разбиваем содержимое ячейки
        UpdateGoogleMap(position[0],position[1]);
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <table class="name_class_table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Координаты</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${listFlood}" var="flood">
            <tr>
                <td class="geo">${flood.geographKoordsPost}</td>
                
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

А если вот так, то работает:

```
addEventListener("click", ({target}) => {
    });
```

Но реагирует на все таблицы, а мне нужно только на одну конкретную.

Comment: `('click', e => {} ....... var tr e.target.closest()..`?

Comment: Попробовал:document.querySelector('table.tablePost').addEventListener("click", e => {
            var tr = e.closest("tbody > tr");
             });            Не сработало. В отладчике подчёркивает addEventListener("click", e

Comment: `e.target.closest`, а не `e.closest`

Comment: document.querySelector('table.tablePost').addEventListener("click", e => {
            var tr =e.target.closest("tbody > tr"); ...}); Не срабатывает, в отладчике подчёркивает .addEventListener("click", e => {

Comment: Да, есть <table class="tablePost"> <tbody>...</tbody> </table>

Comment: Ну я для примера писал 'table.name_class_table', а потом просто поменял name_class_table на конкретное имя

Comment: Да, сработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** Как бы это банально не звучало, но скрипты располагают перед закрывающим тегом `</body>`.

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- Разметка документа -->
  </div>

  <script>
    // ... код
  </script>
</body>
```

**2** Если не хотите перемещать, оборачивайте ваши скрипты, относящиеся к выборке элементов.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // ... код
});
```

**3** В обязательном порядке оборачивайте их, если они расположены во внешних файлах.

```
// внешний файл, например: aditional.js

function clickHandler(event) {
    // ... код
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

  blocks.forEach(function(element, index) {
      element.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  });
});
```

---

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

DOM не загрузился, и вот эта конструкция `document.querySelector('...')` равна **null**. А у нала нет свойства/метода `addEventListener`. [Подробнее ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Return_value)

---

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

DOM не загрузился, и вот эта конструкция `document.getElementsByClassName('...')` возвращает текущую [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName#Syntax) найденных элементов, т.е. **пустую**.

Если вы напишите `console.log(...)`, то можете увидеть, что коллекция не пуста. Потому что `HTMLCollection`, хранящая элементы DOM, является динамической. Но при попытке взять из коллекции элемент с индексом `[0]`, до того как он был отрисован в браузере, получите данную ошибку.

---

Вот ваш код почти без изменений в снипете отрабатывает.

```js
document.querySelector('table.name_class_table').addEventListener("click", ({
  target
}) => {
  var tr = target.closest("tbody > tr");
  if (!tr) return;
  var position = tr.querySelector("td.geo").textContent; //Берём нужную ячейку
  position = position.split(/\s+/).map(Number); //Разбиваем содержимое ячейки
  // UpdateGoogleMap(position[0], position[1]);
  console.log(position)
});
```

```html
<table class="name_class_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Координаты</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!--c:forEach items="${listFlood}" var="flood"-->
    <tr>
      <td class="geo">43.11 131.89</td>
    </tr>
    <!--/c:forEach-->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Они у меня вообще в head прописаны

Comment: Но у меня почему-то не срабатывает, как у вас в примере

Comment: Спасибо! После обёртки заработало.

Comment: Перенёс. Только не пойму почему в head она не срабатывала, я ведь щёлкал после того как страница полностью подгружалась?