# addEventListener не находит элемент

Tags: javascript, html

Есть блок,который должен скрывать в себе еще один, пока не наведут мышку. Пытаюсь привязать через `addEventListener`, выдает ошибку `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined at index.html:26`.

HTML:

```
<div class="block1" style="background-color: red">
    <div class="block2" style="background-color: blue"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block1{
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.block2{
    z-index: 2;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('block1')[0].addEventListener('mouseover', func1);
function func1(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('block2')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Ошибка в хроме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня работает jsfiddle.net/BaNru/a2h0yp87/

Comment: Показанный вами код работает.

Comment: Ваш код `javascript` расположен в отдельном файле?

Comment: @РустамГимранов есть версия как и с тегом script, так и отдельно

Comment: Не этот [случай](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985823/256824) ?

Comment: @РустамГимранов в первом случае, тэг script расположен у меня после закрытия тэга head, перед body. а во втором, файл скрипта подключен в секции head. кроме того, у меня есть несколько скриптов, которые привязаны не по addEventListener, и они прекрасно работают

Comment: Можно добавить атрибут [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/web/html/element/script#Атрибуты) к тегу script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не находит - и не надо. Обойдемся без `addEventListener`.

```css
.block1 {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.block2 {
  z-index: 2;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.block1:hover .block2 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1" style="background-color: red">
  <div class="block2" style="background-color: blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Строго говоря, в оригинальном коде не было поведения на mouseout =)

Comment: @vp_arth Я думаю это "неправильная печать" ("Осенний марафон").

Answer (score 4):

> в первом случае, тэг script расположен у меня после закрытия тэга head, перед body. а во втором, файл скрипта подключен в секции head. кроме того, у меня есть несколько скриптов, которые привязаны не по addEventListener, и они прекрасно работают

Тут всё просто: скрипт начинает работать ранее загрузки контента (HTML)
Поэтому необходимо либо разместить этот код в конце документа (в районе закрывающего body), либо воспользоваться

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Подробности тут https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded

Comment: День добрый. Хотел написать по поводу преобразования в комментарий. При этом действии ваш рейтинг не понижается. -1 связано с тем, что другой участник поставил тревогу на ваш ответ.

Comment: Но в любом случае, на будущее, чтоб такого больше не происходило, старайтесь давать более подробный ответ (я про ваш прошлый), т.к. просто ответ-ссылки не приветствуются.

Answer (score 0):

У меня работает https://jsfiddle.net/BaNru/a2h0yp87/

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('block1')[0].addEventListener('mouseover', func1);
function func1(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('block2')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```css
.block1{
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.block2{
    z-index: 2;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1" style="background-color: red">
    <div class="block2" style="background-color: blue"></div>
</div>
```