# Вылезает ошибка Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null при обращении к select option value

Tags: javascript, select, null

По моей теме здесь уже было не одно обсуждение и, тем не менее, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Задача отработать change у select, чтобы отловить option.value и показать зелёный маркер (принято).
Подсмотрел пару решений и написал на jsbin.com. Работает и всё бы хорошо, но..

```
// -- js --
    var widthValue = 0;
    var widthInfo = document.getElementById('widthInfo');
    var widthSelect = document.getElementById('widthSelect');
    widthInfo.innerHTML = '';
    widthSelect.addEventListener("change", 
        function(e){
            widthValue = widthSelect.value;
            console.log(widthValue);
            widthInfo.innerHTML = '<span class="green"></span>';
        }
    );
// -- html --
div class="item">
    <p><label for="">Ширина (мм):</label></p>
    <select id="widthSelect">
        <option selected disabled value="0">Выбрать...</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="48">48</option>
        <option value="72">72</option>
    </select>
    <div class="report" id="widthInfo"></div>
  </div>
```

Скопировал код, чтоб сохранить себе файлом, и закинул на сервер. Стал проверять файл, браузер выдаёт ошибку: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null. 
Ну и перестал работать мой код.
Стал гуглить... 
Одни при использовании innerHTML пишут так:

```
smth.innerHTML = ('<code></code>');
```

Другие - так:

```
smth.innerHTML = '<code></code>';
```

У меня - без скобок. Если добавить скобки, то тут же Хром начинает ругаться на следом идущий addEventListener.
Вставил этот же код на jsfiddle. Всё работает и никаких ошибок не выводится.
Стоило только перенести весь код в некий обыкновенный index.html и прощай работающий код(
Пожалуйста, помогите. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: где прописан данный Js? если в отдельном файле, то где он подключается?

Comment: в отдельный файл Js-код не выносил пока. Прямо в теле прописан. Тэги script (откр, закр) тоже корректно написал.

Comment: в каком месте файла прописан скрипт?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985823/256824

Comment: сперва идёт скрипт и ниже уже селект

Comment: Перенёс скрипт к закрывающему тэгу </body> и никаких ошибок. Спасибо огромное)