# Не работает addEventListener

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Не работает код. Сам файл подружается всё работает. в коде html такой div с классом "add_new_line" присутствует. в css тоже есть селектор .add_new_line

```
var button = document.querySelector(".add_new_line");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("Кнопка нажата.");
});
```

Выдаёт ошибку

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
>       at add_new_row.js:3

Comment: значит нету елемента с классом `.add_new_line`. Он случайно не появляеться динамически ?

Comment: думаю что нет. код html css прописан и не изменяется

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985823/256824

Answer (score 3):

Ваш код, из описания, работает:

```js
var button = document.querySelector(".add_new_line");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("Кнопка нажата.");
});
```

```html
<button class="add_new_line">Кнопка</button>
```