# Locastorage javascript

Tags: javascript

есть вот такой код.
когда включаю inspect а потом console выдает ошибку:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null localstorage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card">
        <div>
            <img src="https://cdn.tmobile.com/content/dam/t-mobile/en-p/cell-phones/apple/apple-iphone-xs/gold/Apple-iPhoneXs-Gold-1-3x.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:35%">
            <h1>Iphone Xs</h1>
            <p class="price">$1200.99</p>
            <p>Some text about the phone..</p>
            <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
localStorage.setItem("Name", "Iphone");
localStorage.setItem("Price", "1200");

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Name");
```

Comment: Потому что скрипт срабатывает до полной загрузки HTML. Должен сработать, если весь код запихнуть под `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ /* сюда */ });` или добавить тегу script атрибут `<script src="..." defer></script>`

Comment: `document.getElementById('result')` возвращает null потому что в документе нет элемента с ID 'result'.

Comment: я добавил <div id="result"></div> но все равно так пишет

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985823/256824